# Flutter webview doesn't load/redirect page after sending form with Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter

I have a bug in a flutter app that uses a Webview as it's main widget. The website used in the webview if our code also.

The flutter app uses a different method of connecting users, with a bearer token. So far the bearer token seems to work but there are a few cases where there are problems. I have a button in my profile page that is supposed to create a new "adventure" for the user that is stocked in the "adventures" database, associated to his profile. With the normal means of connection on the website, the creation is seamless and the redirection afterwards is too.

When I try to do it in the flutter app though, with the bearer token, the webview becomes blank, the adventure is not created and there is no redirection, so I am stuck on this blank page.

All of this is in a single page, with buttons associated to the different routes (createAventure, updateAdventure, etc.)

Here are some code samples :

The createAdventure function

```
public function createAdventure()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('subscribers')->check() || (Auth::guard('api')->check() && !Auth::guard('api')->user()->isGuestProfile)) {
            $data = Request::all();
            /** @var Subscriber $subscriber */
            if(Auth::guard('subscribers')->check())
            {
                $subscriber = Auth::guard('subscribers')->user();
            }
            else
            {
                $subscriber = Auth::guard('api')->user();
            }
            
            $data['subscriber_id'] = $subscriber->id;
            $data['active'] = true;
            if ($subscriber->adventures()->create($data)) {
                return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#tab-adventures")->with('success', trans('main.form-adventure.edit-success'));
            } else {
                return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#tab-adventures")->with('failure', trans('main.form-adventure.failure'));
            }
        }
    }
```

The div in my blade file where the button and the form is :

```
<div class="adv-tile__text">
                                <a class="edit-adventure call-to-action" id="edit-adventure-{{$adventure->id}}">@lang('main.form-adventure.edit')</a>
                                <a class="add-adventure-step call-to-action" id="add-adventure-step-{{$adventure->id}}">@lang('main.form-adventure-step.add')</a>
                                {{Form::open(['url' => urlRouteName('adventure-step.create'), 'id' => 'form-add-adventure-step-' . $adventure->id, 'class' => 'form', 'style' => 'display:none', 'files' => 'true','method'=>'post'])}}
                                    <div class="form__column element-spacing">
                                        {{Form::label('label', trans('main.form-adventure-step.label'))}}
                                        {{Form::text('label', '')}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form__column element-spacing">
                                        {{Form::label('description', trans('main.form-adventure-step.description'))}}
                                        {{Form::text('description', '')}}
                                    </div>
                                    {{--<div class="form__column element-spacing">
                                        {{Form::label('url', trans('main.form-adventure-step.url'))}}
                                        {{Form::file('url')}}
                                    </div>--}}
                                    <div class="form__column element-spacing"  data-component="chooseRegion" data-csrf="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                        {{Form::label('latitude', trans('main.form-adventure-step.map'), ['style' => 'display:none', 'data-ref' => 'mapLabel'])}}
                                        <div data-ref="map" class="profile__google-maps"></div>
                                        {{Form::hidden('latitude', '', ['id' => 'latitude'])}}
                                        {{Form::hidden('longitude', '', ['id' => 'longitude'])}}
                                        {{Form::label('interest_location_id', trans('main.form-adventure-step.interest_location_id'))}}
                                        {{Form::select('interest_location_id', ['' => trans('properties.please_select')], '', ['data-ref' => 'select'])}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form__column element-spacing">
                                        {{Form::hidden('adventure_id', $adventure->id)}}
                                        {{Form::submit(trans('main.form-adventure-step.submit'), ['class'=> 'call-to-action'])}}
                                        <a id="cancel-add-adventure-step-{{$adventure->id}}" class="cancel-add-adventure-step call-to-action">@lang('main.form-adventure-step.cancel')</a>
                                </div>
```

InAppWebView in flutter :

```
Stack createAppContent(HomePageState state) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialOptions: _options,
              androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
                  (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
                return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
                    origin: origin, allow: true, retain: true);
              },
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
                _permissionStatus();
                context.read<LoginBloc>().webViewController = controller;
                context
                    .read<HomePageBloc>()
                    .add(WebviewCreated(webViewController: controller));
              },
              shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) {
                if (Platform.isIOS &&
                    (navigationAction.request.headers!['Content-Type'] !=
                            null ||
                        navigationAction.request.headers!['Accept-Encoding'] !=
                            null)) {
                  return Future.value(NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW);
                }
                if (navigationAction.request.headers != null &&
                    navigationAction.request.headers!['Authorization'] !=
                        null) {
                  return Future.value(NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW);
                } else if (navigationAction.request.url!.path != 'blank') {
                  BlocProvider.of<HomePageBloc>(context).add(
                    LoadUri(navigationAction.request.url),
                  );

                  return Future.value(NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL);
                } else {
                  return Future.value(NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          if (state is HomePageInitial)
            const SafeArea(
                child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
              ),
            )),
          if (state is ShowingLoginPart ||
              context.read<LoginBloc>().state is LoginFailure)
            const LoginPart(),
          if (state is ShowingAgreementPart) const AgreementPart(),
          if (state is ShowingRegisterPart ||
              context.read<RegisterBloc>().state is RegisterFailure)
            const RegisterPart(),
        ],
      );
    }
```

I tried going to the "createAdventure" route in postman, with the bearer token in my header and the form infos and the adventure gets created and I can see it on the website. So I know the verification of the token is done and associated to the right account.

If there is any more info needed, please let me know and I will provide it.